# Converting Grayscale Image to RGB and Vice veras

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv

I wrote a code to convert ground truth grayscale mask to RGB, and Vice Versa, but RGB2Grayscales does not work as expected?

**Example of label, and converted RGB**

[image: label_image]

[image: Color_image]

```
from __future__ import print_function, absolute_import, division
from collections import namedtuple
import numpy as np
import cv2

Label = namedtuple('Label',
                   ['name', 'id', 'trainId', 'category', 'categoryId', 'hasInstances', 'ignoreInEval', 'color', ])

labels = [
    #       name                     id    trainId   category            catId     hasInstances   ignoreInEval   color
    Label('unlabeled', 0, 19, 'void', 0, False, True, (0, 0, 0)),
    Label('ego vehicle', 1, 19, 'void', 0, False, True, (0, 0, 0)),
    Label('rectification border', 2, 19, 'void', 0, False, True, (0, 0, 0)),
    Label('out of roi', 3, 19, 'void', 0, False, True, (0, 0, 0)),
    Label('static', 4, 19, 'void', 0, False, True, (0, 0, 0)),
    Label('dynamic', 5, 19, 'void', 0, False, True, (111, 74, 0)),
    Label('ground', 6, 19, 'void', 0, False, True, (81, 0, 81)),
    Label('road', 7, 0, 'flat', 1, False, False, (128, 64, 128)),
    Label('sidewalk', 8, 1, 'flat', 1, False, False, (244, 35, 232)),
    Label('parking', 9, 19, 'flat', 1, False, True, (250, 170, 160)),
    Label('rail track', 10, 19, 'flat', 1, False, True, (230, 150, 140)),
    Label('building', 11, 2, 'construction', 2, False, False, (70, 70, 70)),
    Label('wall', 12, 3, 'construction', 2, False, False, (102, 102, 156)),
    Label('fence', 13, 4, 'construction', 2, False, False, (190, 153, 153)),
    Label('guard rail', 14, 19, 'construction', 2, False, True, (180, 165, 180)),
    Label('bridge', 15, 19, 'construction', 2, False, True, (150, 100, 100)),
    Label('tunnel', 16, 19, 'construction', 2, False, True, (150, 120, 90)),
    Label('pole', 17, 5, 'object', 3, False, False, (153, 153, 153)),
    Label('polegroup', 18, 19, 'object', 3, False, True, (153, 153, 153)),
    Label('traffic light', 19, 6, 'object', 3, False, False, (250, 170, 30)),
    Label('traffic sign', 20, 7, 'object', 3, False, False, (220, 220, 0)),
    Label('vegetation', 21, 8, 'nature', 4, False, False, (107, 142, 35)),
    Label('terrain', 22, 9, 'nature', 4, False, False, (152, 251, 152)),
    Label('sky', 23, 10, 'sky', 5, False, False, (70, 130, 180)),
    Label('person', 24, 11, 'human', 6, True, False, (220, 20, 60)),
    Label('rider', 25, 12, 'human', 6, True, False, (255, 0, 0)),
    Label('car', 26, 13, 'vehicle', 7, True, False, (0, 0, 142)),
    Label('truck', 27, 14, 'vehicle', 7, True, False, (0, 0, 70)),
    Label('bus', 28, 15, 'vehicle', 7, True, False, (0, 60, 100)),
    Label('caravan', 29, 19, 'vehicle', 7, True, True, (0, 0, 90)),
    Label('trailer', 30, 19, 'vehicle', 7, True, True, (0, 0, 110)),
    Label('train', 31, 16, 'vehicle', 7, True, False, (0, 80, 100)),
    Label('motorcycle', 32, 17, 'vehicle', 7, True, False, (0, 0, 230)),
    Label('bicycle', 33, 18, 'vehicle', 7, True, False, (119, 11, 32)),
    Label('license plate', -1, -1, 'vehicle', 7, False, True, (0, 0, 142)),
]


def trainIdToColor(trainId: int):
    for l in labels:
        if l.trainId == trainId:
            color = l.color
            break
    return color


def colortoTrainId(rgbColor):
    trainId = 0
    for l in labels:
        if l.color == rgbColor:
            trainId = l.trainId
            break
    return trainId


def gray2color(grayImage:np.ndarray,num_class:int):
    rgbImage=np.zeros((grayImage.shape[0],grayImage.shape[1],3),dtype='uint8')
    for cls in range(num_class):
        row,col=np.where(grayImage==cls)
        if (len(row)==0):
            continue
        color=trainIdToColor(cls)
        rgbImage[row,col]=color
    return rgbImage


def color2gray(colorImage:np.ndarray, bgr_color_space:bool):
    if bgr_color_space:
        colorImage = cv2.cvtColor(colorImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


    unique_color=np.unique(colorImage.reshape(-1, colorImage.shape[2]), axis=0)
    gray=np.zeros((colorImage.shape[0],colorImage.shape[1]),dtype=np.float32)
    for uc in unique_color:

        where_cond1= np.logical_and(colorImage[:,:,0]==uc[0],
                                    colorImage[:,:,1]==uc[1],
                                    colorImage[:,:,2]==uc[2])
        row,col=np.where(where_cond1)
        gray[row,col]=colortoTrainId(tuple(uc))

    return gray
```

when I use **gray2color** Everythings works fine. but when I try to convert an RGB image via **color2gray**, it converts but the result is not the same as original gray image. **(changes 19s to 13, other classes are fine)**. I checked to code multiple times but I don't know why I got bad results.
**for clarification**
as you can see in returned grayscale there's no 19 value,all added up to 13s.

```
original grayscale:
unique: 0   1   2   4   5   7   8   10  11  13  19
count:  624649  168701  819940  2802    24885   12192   42082   37098   6791    115270  242742

returned grayscale:
unique: 0   1   2   4   5   7   8   10  11  13
count:  624649  168701  819940  2802    24885   12192   42082   37098   6791    358012
```

also **color2gray** function is very slow and time-consuming!

Comment: You appear to have made `gray` an `np.float32`?

Comment: yeah, what is this going to do with my problem? (19 replaced by 13) @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 0):

your trainId value is too low that's why your grayscale image is very dark. Increase the value of trainId in the Labels list and make your gray image datatype to be uint8

```
def color2gray(colorImage:np.ndarray, bgr_color_space:bool):
    if bgr_color_space:
        colorImage = cv2.cvtColor(colorImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


    gray=np.zeros((colorImage.shape[0],colorImage.shape[1]),dtype=np.uint8)

    for row in range(colorImage.shape[0]):
        for col in range(colorImage.shape[1]):
            # either multiply the result of colortoTrainId(tuple(uc)) with some number
            # or change the value of trainId in the Labels list
            gray[row,col]=colortoTrainId(tuple(colorImage[row,col]))*10

    return gray
```

Comment: the grayscales image is not meant to be displayed, it's a mask for NN output.
and this not my problem, the problem is when I looking to returned grayscale matrix any 19 value is replaced with 13. and that's weird.

Comment: i have changed my answer too. And now you will get 190 (i.e 19) in the gray image but as you are doing pixelwise operations so this will be time consuming

Comment: look on my on code one more time, it's not pixel-wise. and again same problems

Comment: yes, your code is pixel wise. see these two lines `row,col=np.where(where_cond1)`
        `gray[row,col]=colortoTrainId(tuple(uc))`. You are finding the locations where specific color lies and then assigning value to those locations in gray image

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of 1 question myself

`np.logical_and()` just take two arrays

so it must be used nested like this

```
where_cond1=np.logical_and(np.logical_and(colorImage[:,:,0]==uc[0],colorImage[:,:,1]==uc[1]), colorImage[:,:,2]==uc[2])
```

but the speed problem remains, any idea how to vectorize assignment?

Comment: some one voted negative but the problem is sovled with this